# Default lead conversion doesn't work when there is a saveUrl parameter in the url

Tags: conversion

I created a custom convert button for leads like that : `/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}&saveURL=/apex/MyPage?id={!Lead.Id}`

The button is present on the standard Lead page layout as a detail page button, so no code.

Unfortunaly, the lead conversion doesn't work because in my Visualforce page, when I get the Lead.Id parameter, the `ConvertedAccountId` field is null.

I don't understand what fails during the conversion process.

Can you help me please?

Thank for your response.

Comment: For anyone who might be able to answer your question, I'm confident they'd want to be able to see the code for the page your button is linked to and very likely the code for the controller too. Please use the edit button to update your post.

Comment: My button  is present on the standard Lead page layout as a detail page button, so no code.

Comment: Your visualforce query the ConvertedAccountId from the lead that's right ? Are you always creating a contact or an opportunity ? You can query the AccountId from these one

Comment: Yes, ConvertedAccountId field is null when I query it after the lead conversion.

Comment: I think the problem is we only see part of the process here. It looks like you're calling the standard lead convert URL with a redirect URL to go to your visualforce page on save. I'm confused. Is the lead really not being converted? Or is your page just failing to display after the save?

Comment: So you try to go back to the lead after the supposed convert and there is no value in the field you expect to be populated.

Comment: The lead is not converted because if I go on the lead page layout, there is not an error message which explains my lead is converted.

Comment: So I just threw together a test to try this out, and it should work. The question is why isn't the lead being converted? Have you looked into the debug logs to try to trace down the root cause? Is there any other code on Lead? Are there any triggers? Could there be an exception that is being swallowed by an empty catch block that then allows your page to render despite the failure of the lead to convert.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why my lead is not converted.

I have looked in the debug logs and there is nothing about the conversion page, I just have logs for my next Visualforce page and if I see the details, there is no much lines and no error.

I have trigger on lead but it's an after insert trigger.

I don't see logs about the conversion in the debug logs, is it normal?
Only logs about my next Visualforce page.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem.

I have a 'before update' trigger on Account  which verify if a field of the account is correct.

If it's not, there is an addError method on the record so the account is not updated and the lead is not converted.

Why the account has to be updated on the lead conversion process?
Which field of the account is updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating an Opportunity or a Contact on each convertion, you can use the ConvertedOpportunityId or the ConvertedContactId in order to query the AccountId when the ConvertedAccountId is null

Comment: The problem is the lead conversion fails entirely. There is *always* at the very least an account and a contact when lead conversion is complete...opportunity is optional. So being able to query `ConvertedAccountId` should be a given.